# Regex to negate accepting numbers with leading zeros

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

So below is the directive i am using to ensure the input is purely number from 0-9.

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[numbersOnly]",
})
export class OnlynumberDirective {
  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) {}

  @HostListener("input", ["$event"]) onInputChange(event) {
    const initalValue = this._el.nativeElement.value;

    this._el.nativeElement.value = initalValue.replace(/[^0-9]*/g, "");
    if (initalValue !== this._el.nativeElement.value) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  }
}
```

At the moment, it only allows numbers (no special characters) as it performs data cleanup and replaces the non-numeric chars with empty space. Now i want to change my regex to not allow numbers containing leading zeros. It can have zeros but not just in the start.

1. 90123 -> Accepted
2. 100001 -> Accepted
3. 01223 -> Not accepted
4. 0 -> Not accepted

Please suggest me a regex that can work with this.

Comment: Are you performing validation or data cleanup?

Comment: `/\D|^0+/g` would work if your cleaning the data for the user. `/^[1-9]\d*$/g` would work for validation.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus data cleanup, and i used /\D|^0+/g for data cleanup and it worked! Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `/\D|^0+/g` for data cleanup like so:

```
initalValue.replace(/\D|^0+/g, "");
```

In English it says:

> Find anything not a digit (`\D`) or (`|`) leading zeros (`^0+`) and replace it with nothing

```js
console.log('90123'.replace(/\D|^0+/g, ""));
console.log('100001'.replace(/\D|^0+/g, ""));
console.log('01223'.replace(/\D|^0+/g, ""));
console.log('001223'.replace(/\D|^0+/g, ""));
console.log('0'.replace(/\D|^0+/g, ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use

```
/^[^1-9]+/g
```

Leading **^** character that is not **^** number 1 to 9

```js
console.log('00090123'.replace(/^[^1-9]+/g, ""));
console.log('100001'.replace(/^[^1-9]+/g, ""));
console.log('01223'.replace(/^[^1-9]+/g, ""));
console.log('001223'.replace(/^[^1-9]+/g, ""));
console.log('0'.replace(/^[^1-9]+/g, ""));
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

```js
var str="90123 "
var str1="100001"
var str3="01223" 

pattern=/^0|D{1}\d+/g

console.log(str.replace(pattern,""))
console.log(str1.replace(pattern,""))
console.log(str3.replace(pattern,""))
```